# How to set thousand separator and return double value?

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

I have code which set thousand separator:

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    String separator = formatter.format(20000);
```

Problem is that it returns String value but i need  to return double, so i tried to parse it:

```
Double.parseDouble(separator);
```

After this i get error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20,000"`

How can i return double value from my String result?

Comment: at which line do you get that error?

Comment: You can use the same `formatter` you have created to parse the string. `formatter.parse("20,000");`. But if you're doing all that in the same method, you're not accomplishing anything.

Comment: Are you trying to return a `double` value that specifies a particular formatting? because that is impossible.

Comment: Actual numbers do not have separators. Only the string or printed form of the numbers have such things.

Comment: @khelwood i put 20000 just for example, it will get value from method argument, so in reality i have `formatter.parse(number);`.

Comment: @NomadMaker so is there is no way to have double value display like this:`20,000`.?

Comment: sure there is, just use your formatter.

Comment: Yes, you can display numbers anyway you want to. NumberFormat is the class you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @khelwood in the comments: Use [NumberFormat.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

```
double value = formatter.parse(separator).doubleValue();
```

Comment: well it's not working, i don't have an error but i get full number without comma.

Comment: @NemJov yes, because it's a `double` and number datatypes don't have formatting information, as this is of no meaning for working with numbers. If you want to display a number in a certain format, use `NumberFormat.format`. If you have a string representation of a number in a certain format and want to do computations with it, use `NumberFormat.parse` to convert it to a number datatype.

Comment: @NemJov You can only put a comma inside a string, not a double. What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: @NemJov, maybe post the actual code that you want working, so we get a better idea of what your real problem is